# download image from SharePoint Online using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to download Images from SharePoint Online site . Here is my code it will give webclient Exception.

```
            var securedPassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var c in password.ToCharArray()) securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword);
            DownloadFile(url, credentials, "https://damasjewellery.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/Products/Catalogue%20Images/BDR-001-NA-RG-X-0.JPG?csf=1&e=FclkOs");
```

DownloadFile Method Contains Webclient Object And Its DownloadFIle method. When I pass Url and path of Particular Images It will Give me an exception .

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            client.DownloadFile(webUrl, fileRelativeUrl);
        }
```

Comment: Could you please share detailed exception information ?

Answer (score 0):

A WebClient Exception usually means there's some kind of connection issue. Either the server returned a 404, the server timed out, there's no internet connection, or you're having a permissions issue.

*Edit: Realized the exception being thrown was already in the question.

Try swapping url to uri.

```
public void DownloadFile(
    Uri address,
    string fileName
)
```